# Kobo Comma Separated Loop Data to List - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

We have a kobo survey that collects data in loops. We ask each person how many devices you own and when was the purchase date for each. The output data looks like this:

[image]

I want to import the excel data into a python data frame then do the clean up to have it like this:

[image]

I have been able to import the data but got stuck at the implementation and cleanup:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('DataFile.xlsx')
print(df) 
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hello ~  It would be better if you tried writing some code first and then share what you have tried along with a specific error encountered, otherwise your question becomes a 'give me the code' type of question.

Comment: hello thank you for the tip I understand now, will take into consideration in future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly make use of `rstrip()` method and `split()` method:

```
df['Devices']=df['Devices'].str.rstrip(';').str.split(';')
df['Purchase Date']=df['Purchase Date'].str.rstrip(';').str.split(';')
```

Finally use `explode()` method:

```
df_out=df.explode('Devices')
df_out['Purchase Date']=df['Purchase Date'].explode()
```

Now If you print `df_out` you will get your desired output